# Why cv2.VideoWriter in python changes the defined color

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, video, rgb

In the code below I defined the color of the rectangle as `fc='#fff300'` which the RGB is `(255,163,0)`. Therefore, all the frames of the video should have the above color, but the RGB of the video is `(36,255,219)` which is totally another color.

I am wondering how to keep the color of the rectangle for the video as well?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from cv2 import VideoWriter, VideoWriter_fourcc


pixels = 600
my_dpi = 100
FPS=1

for i in range(5):
    fig = plt.figure(5,figsize=( pixels/my_dpi,  pixels/my_dpi),facecolor='k', dpi=my_dpi)  
    plt.axes([0,0,1,1])
    rectangle = plt.Rectangle((-300, -300), 600, 600, fc='#fff300')
    plt.gca().add_patch(rectangle)
    plt.savefig('1.png',dpi=my_dpi)
    plt.show()
    
    fig.canvas.draw()  # draw the figure 
       
    data = np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8)  #  save it to a numpy array.
    data = data.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,)) 
    
    fourcc = VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP42')
    video = VideoWriter(('1.mp4'), fourcc, FPS, (pixels, pixels))
    
    video.write(data)
video.release()
```

Comment: OpenCV uses **BRG** color format (and matplotlib uses RGB color format). Use: `video.write(cv2.cvtColor(data, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))`. There is another issue: You are opening the video file multiple times in a loop. You may use `if i == 0:` ... `video = cv2.VideoWriter(('1.mp4'), fourcc, FPS, (pixels, pixels))`. When executing the code I am getting a warning: "codec msmpeg4v2 in stream #0, codec not currently supported". If there is a codec issue, try `fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')`

Comment: Using `video.write(cv2.cvtColor(data, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))` solved the color's issue but the size of the video increased from around 200kb to more than 4000kb which is not suitable for me since I have thousands of them. Is there any way to keep the size the same as before `RGB2BGR`.

Comment: I don't think the larger size is related to RGB2BGR. I don't understand the context of "having thousands of them". Thousands of video files with solid color (like the yellow video)?

Comment: The above code was just a simplified version of my original code. The main code generates thousands of videos which each video has 100 frames with FPS=1. The background color is black and each frame has a colored line which the color varies in frames.

Comment: 4000KB for 100 frames, it is just 40KB per frame. I don't think I can help you with that.

Comment: Do you mean this is the minimum possible size for each frame?

Comment: No, but OpenCV VideoWriter has not options to set the video bitrate (or compression ratio). The file size is not related to your posted question, and I don't want to start a discussion about video codecs and bitrates.